# Script task component is not working without Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, script-task

I have the packages in SSISDB catalog which is having script task component with C# code in it & I’m not having visual studio in that server.I’m trying to run the packages through Job but the script task is not validated during execution & it is not failing.

I have tried changing the targeted version to 2017

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your problem description is not very clear. You can provide some functional description and code of your project. And if VS reports an error, you can share the error.